# Add a clickable image to a GridView in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, hyperlink

I'm trying to add an delete image at the end of each row in a GridView. I want the user to be able to click the image to delete the row.

So I've used a HyperLinkField to create a link to another page which will delete the record:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" 
                        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="RemoveLine.aspx?ID={0}"                             
                        Target="_blank"   />
```

The HyperLinkField doesn't contain an Image tag so I created a TemplateField with an Image inside.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imageRemove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/smallcross.gif"  />                                
    </ItemTemplate>                        
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However the HyperLinkField and Image appear in different columns and the image has no click event.

Any way of combining the two?

I'm using ASP.Net 4.0.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Normally you need to identify which record you want to delete, you can use the **CommadArgument** property to identify the record's Id:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="40">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server"  
            ImageUrl="~/Imags/delete.png" OnClick="ButtonDelete_Click" ToolTip="Delete"
            CommandArgument='<%#Bind("UserId")%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton button = sender as ImageButton;
    DeleteUserById(Convert.ToInt32(button.CommandArgument));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server"  
        ImageUrl="~/Imags/delete.png" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"
 ToolTip="Delete row" CommandName="Eliminar" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserId")%>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

You can use the CommandArgument to pass the ID value of the selected row and perform
 the desires results

```
// fires when the ImageButton gets clicked
protected void GridView1_ItemCommand(object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Commandname ="Eliminar"){
  this.Eliminar(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));

}
```

}

```
// function to delete the record
 private void Eliminar(int code)
 { 
    //custom code to delete the records
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an image button?

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl="~/Images/smallcross.gif" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your image with a raw anchor tag , you get the same result.

```
<asp:TemplateField>

<ItemTemplate>

<a href="RemoveLine.aspx?ID={0}">      
<asp:Image ID="imageRemove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/smallcross.gif" />                                              
</a>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I pass the ID in?